# Axios is not getting data from server after several request

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, axios

I have React & NodeJS application and i am fetching data from server and it works but only for several requests, after 5 or 6 reloading of page axios is not getting data anymore, i am not using any rate limiting.

```
axios.get('/api/customer-base/')
.then(res => res.data)
.then(data=>{
    console.log(`${data.rooms} dasd`)
    dispatch({
        type: FETCH_ROOMS,
        payload: {
            rooms: JSON.parse(data.rooms),
            loading: false
        }
    })
})
.catch(err=>{
     if(err.response.data.redirect){
         window.location.replace(err.response.data.redirect)
     }else{
         dispatch({
             type: CUSTOMER_BASE_ERROR,
             payload: {
                 error: err.response.data.message
             }
         })
     }
})
```

here is axios code. and here is Express

```
router.get('/', async (req,res)=>{
    try{
        let rooms = await Rooms.find({}).populate('reserver');
        console.log(rooms);
        return res.status(200).send({
           rooms: JSON.stringify(rooms)
        })
    }catch(err){
        return res.status(500).send({
            message: err.message
        })
     }
 })
```

so what is problem? did you have this kind of problem?

Comment: did you try with absolute URLs for the requests from the UI side? Does the network tab in dev-tools display the API request you want to make, any HTTP errors you see in the same tab?

Comment: it may be a cache issue, can you add a timestamp your axios url and try?
axios.get(`/api/customer-base?timestamp=${new Date().getTime()}`)

Comment: after disconnecting from server it logs network error in console

Comment: what should i do when i add timestamp?

Comment: you will try and check if the problem continues or not.

Comment: it continues for last time it took 42 sec to send request before disconnecting and it did not

Comment: by the way you can return your data like this:  return res.status(200).json({rooms})

Comment: yeah but first i want to solve my problem. if it is cache error if i delete caches will it work?

Comment: Pointing to something else: You don't really need two `.then(r => ...)` at the axios because the first `then` is not really resolving a `promise`, just fetching a property from `res` as `data`. Coming to your problem: Check via `console` that at every reload if the request reaches the route controller or not.

Comment: @ambianBeing no it does not it stops getting request after 6th or fifth request

Comment: @iLiA Since `GET` requests are cached, clearing it out and checking is good start to debug this.

Comment: No, clearing cache does not solves problem

Comment: i changed get to post and it works same way